# List not getting initialized c#

Tags: c#, list, static, initialization

For the following code below, the foreach loop in the main() method is not displaying any values. i.e. my list is not getting initialized for display. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample
{
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 
public class Program
{
    public static List<Product> allProducts;

    public static void InitialiseMyProducts(List<Product> allProducts)
    {
        allProducts = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product(){Id=1,Name="TV"},
            new Product(){Id=2,Name="Bat"},
            new Product(){Id=3,Name="Ball"},
            new Product(){Id=4,Name="Chair"},
        };
    }       

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> allProducts = new List<Product>();
        allProducts = new List<Product>();
        InitialiseProductList(allProducts);
        foreach (Product res in allProducts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID:" + " " + res.Id + " " + "Name:" + " " + res.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `allProducts` as both a local and class level variable. Use either-or, not both.

Answer (score 6):

You've got several variables all called `allProducts`:

- The static variable
- The parameter in `InitialiseMyProducts`
- The local variable in `Main`

You're initializing the local variable in `Main` twice, then passing it to `InitialiseMyProducts` (or `InitialiseProductList` - you've changed the name half way through). However, the method then ignores the previous value and changes the *parameter* to refer to another list. That's irrelevant to `Main`, because the argument has been [passed by value](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).

I would suggest one of two separate options:

- Remove the `static` variable entirely, and make `InitialiseProductList` *return* a `List<Product>`
- Return *all* the declarations apart from the one for the static variable; `InitialiseProductList` should have no parameters

The most important thing is first to understand *why* the existing code doesn't work though. Make sure all of the description above makes sense, and feel free to ask questions for extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sample
{
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 
public class Program
{
    public static List<Product> allProducts;

    public static void InitialiseMyProducts()
    {
        allProducts = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product(){Id=1,Name="TV"},
            new Product(){Id=2,Name="Bat"},
            new Product(){Id=3,Name="Ball"},
            new Product(){Id=4,Name="Chair"},
        };
    }       

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitialiseProductList();
        foreach (Product res in allProducts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID:" + " " + res.Id + " " + "Name:" + " " + res.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Product> allProducts = InitialiseProductList(allProducts);
        foreach (Product res in allProducts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID:" + " " + res.Id + " " + "Name:" + " " + res.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```